# popup dismiss on touch outside of popup

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have two layouts one layout 80% of screen and other 20% of screen(lanscape mode), on 20% of screen layout i have few buttons vertically.on click of each button popup window will come on 80% screen layout,on touch outside popup window, popup window will get dismiss. my problem is on touch 80%screen the popup should dismiss not on 20% screen.

```
Ref_channel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {               

                Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                width_device = size.x;
                X = (width_device - Ref_channel.getWidth());

                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                        .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.refchannel_popup,
                        null);
                popupView.measure(
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                int s = X - (int) ((popupView.getMeasuredWidth()));

                pup1 = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                pup1.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());                   
                pup1.setFocusable(true);                    
                pup1.showAtLocation(Ref_channel, 0, s, 0);

        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. In 80% layout, creating layout.setontouchlistener and in action_down i'm dismissing the popup window. ref_pup.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

You have used : `pup1.setOutsideTouchable(true);`

Set this property to "false".

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
pup1.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

with this:

```
pup1.setOutsideTouchable(false);
```

Comment: there no such method in PopupWindow